Same Period Last year for last 2 months in 100% stacked column Chart
I have a 100% stacked column chart which displays the sales amount and percentage for different regions and its working,
but for same period last year its not working out but have manually applied filters for the months, when used the dax below its not taking country as a legend
SPLY Sales for Top 2 Months =
CALCULATE(
[SPLY Sales],
FILTER(
ALL(Calendar),
[Rank by Sales] <= 2
)
)
Top 2 Months Sales =
CALCULATE(
[Total Sales],
FILTER(
ALL(Calendar),
[Rank by Sales] <= 2
)
)
have tried these measures but when using these measures in 100% stacked column visual its not working and in legend the country column isnt accepting
Needs to show something like this
enter image description here
